# Toolbar with alpha-blended icons not displaying properly on one WinXP installation

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I, or rather one of my users, has a very weird issue with alpha-blended icons that don't show correctly on his Windows XP installation. Usually alpha-blended icons shouldn't be a problem on XP and newer, but this one is really puzzling me.

I have an MFC CToolBar, so pretty much a normal WinAPI toolbar, and I'm feeding it with a CImageList (so basically a normal WinAPI image list). There is fallback code for screen modes < 32-bit or older operating systems, which reads my bitmap with 8-bit transparency and reduces it to pre-multiplied 1-bit transparency. On XP, with 32-bit bit depth (confirmed by the user that he uses these settings, and the icons actually show up correctly with 16-bit bit depth because of the fallback code), I create the image list with the `ILC_COLOR32` flag, as indicated in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761389%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#icons). Furthermore, the bitmap that's fed into the image list is created with `CreateCompatibleBitmap` (bitcount = 32, planes = 1).

On all systems I have personally tested so far, this work as intended, i.e. I get nice alpha-blended 32-bit icons on my toolbar. However, on the user's XP installation, it looks like this: http://bugs.openmpt.org/file_download.php?file_id=102&type=bug
This is what the icons look like if the alpha channel is completely ignored (you can tell by some error pixels that are normally invisible because the alpha channel is fully transparent). So despite being on XP, and despite using 32-bit screen mode, and despite using `ILC_COLOR32`, the alpha channel is ignored completely.

I have never seen such behaviour before, and apparently the user doesn't experience this problem with other applications. Is there anything I missed that I have to keep in mind when using alpha-blended images on toolbars on WinXP?

The relevant code for creating the image list images can be found [here](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/modplug/code/trunk/OpenMPT/mptrack/CImageListEx.cpp) (code for 32-bit screen mode is at the bottom) and [there](http://svn.code.sf.net/p/modplug/code/trunk/OpenMPT/mptrack/PNG.cpp) (specifically PNG::Bitmap::ToDIB).

Comment: I am not the down voter, but if you do not put a small, compilable version of your problem code segment here, it will be difficult for people to make useful comments on a solution.  ***[SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/)***

Comment: XP is out of support. Those icons would be terrible even if the alpha channel worked. If this is the highest priority bug you have take a holiday!!! But really asking anyone to spend time on a problem which is merely cosmetic and only affects an obsolete operating system, and can be worked around just by using a 256 colour icons instead....

Comment: ryyker: As a start, I was more interested in knowing if anyone is familiar with these symptoms. I don't think that the behaviour exposed on the user's setup is supposed to happen on a normal Windows installation, but maybe people are aware of flags that need to be passed e.g. when creating the image list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't done this in a while, but I believe you need to create a 32-bpp DIBSECTION rather than a compatible bitmap to pass into the toolbar, otherwise the alpha channel can be lost--even on a system with a 32-bpp display.

Comment: Aha, interesting. Apparently, either using `CreateBitmap` (without the "compatible" part) or `CreateDIBSection` seem to work. Great!

Comment: Update: now it seems that both `CreateDIBSection` and `CreateBitmap` fail on RDP sessions. Only `CreateCompatibleBitmap` works there, but the problem is that the other function don't actually return an error, they just result in black icons, so I cannot dynamically switch between the two approaches... any ideas?

Comment: That's the first mention of remote desktop in this thread.  I wouldn't be surprised if there are some limitations there, but there must be a way to work around them since many other applications show proper toolbar icons over remote desktop.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm wondering about, too. I tried modifying the original `CreateCompatibleBitmap` call a bit (previously, it was using the desktop DC rather than the toolbar DC due to a typo), but while this works in the RDP scenario, it still won't work in the original scenario.